# Prism 6.1 ViewModelLocator doesn't instantiate my ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, viewmodellocator

I just set up a new project recently, using Prism 6.1(with Unity).

I've my bootstrapper:

```
public class ServerBootstrapper : UnityBootstrapper
{
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return Container.Resolve<MainShell>();
    }
    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        Application.Current.MainWindow = (Window)Shell;
        Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
    protected override void ConfigureModuleCatalog()
    {
        base.ConfigureModuleCatalog();
        ModuleCatalog catalog = (ModuleCatalog)ModuleCatalog;
        catalog.AddModule(typeof(ServerUIModule));
    }
}
```

The MainShell:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding DataContext.Title}" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TabControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static infrastructure:RegionsNames.MAIN_TAB_REGION}" />
</DockPanel>
```

My Module definition:

```
public class ServerUIModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager m_regionManager;

    public ServerUIModule( IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        m_container = container;
        m_regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        m_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MAIN_TAB_REGION, typeof(StatusView));
        m_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion(RegionsNames.MAIN_TAB_REGION, typeof(LogMessagesView));
    }
}
```

My StatusView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Xms.Server.UI.Views.StatusView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Xms.Server.UI.Views"
             xmlns:mvvm="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:statusControl="clr-namespace:Xms.Server.UI.Views.StatusControl"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="Aquamarine" mvvm:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock>Content</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The corresponding ViewModel:

```
public class StatusViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public String Title => LocalizedResources.StatusModuleTitle;

    public StatusViewModel()
    {
        //This constructor is never called
    }
}
```

The issue is that my constructor is never called, my DataContext is not set.

How can I debug this? What could I've done wrong?

Comment: StatusView is created but not StatusViewModel?

Comment: @Haukinger Exactly, but with the `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"` It should find the ViewModel matching the View(6.1 convention is to add "Model" to the "XxxxView" to search the class). But I can't find any log indicating it failed to find it, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure that the views reside in a `Views` namespace, and the viewmodels in `ViewModels`, respectively.

Second, the easiest way of debugging this type of things is copying some code from the prism sources and put this in `MyBootstrapper.ConfigureContainer`:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver( x =>
                                                                     {
                                                                         var viewName = x.FullName;
                                                                         viewName = viewName.Replace( ".Views.", ".ViewModels." );
                                                                         var viewAssemblyName = x.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
                                                                         var suffix = viewName.EndsWith( "View" ) ? "Model" : "ViewModel";
                                                                         var viewModelName = string.Format( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}, {2}", viewName, suffix, viewAssemblyName );
                                                                         return Type.GetType( viewModelName );
                                                                     } );
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory( type => Container.Resolve( type ) );
```

...and put breakpoints there to see exactly what's the problem. Alternatively, dig into your `XamlParseException`'s `InnerException`s... at about the third level you should find the real problem. But I find my breakpoint-approach more convenient.

Comment: Views/ViewsModels namespace is wrong. This was correct with Prism 5, but according to their release note, I understood their changed their default naming convention?

I will test your Code(but I guess it should be placed in `ConfigureViewModelLocator`, not `ConfigureContainer`

Comment: Well, it seems I misunderstood the change of convention(Brian Lagunas was recommanding to change the convention, and since he is the new owner, I thought it was following his own recommandation. Anyway, I changed the convention myself, everything is working now.